# Alternative methods of switching high currents other than a relay

Tags: switches, relay, high-voltage, high-current

What are the alternatives to switching high currents (or voltages) of electricity, besides a relay?

A relay is all good and well, but it is rather bulky and requires almost 75% of the relays rated voltage to make it switch. What are the best alternatives to switching high currents and voltages other than a relay?

**UPDATE**

The switching device needs to be activatable via an Arduino board.

My voltage range is around 48v - 60v.
My current range is around 1A - 120A

Comment: "*... requires almost 75% of the relays rated voltage to make it switch.*" Why is that a problem?

Comment: solid state relay maybe, contactor, both more bulky,... "requires almost 75% of the relays rated voltage to make it switch.", what's the problem with that?

Comment: @Transistor "... requires almost 75% of the relays rated voltage to make it switch.", the problem with that is because i want to be able to activate the relay via a microcontroller board, and the microcontroller board can only output 5v 200mA. not nearly enough to power up a relay if the relay was rated for 48v

Comment: You are confusing the coil/control voltage with the contact voltage rating.  It is not unusual to find a relay that requires 5 volts to switch where the contacts are rated to switch 120 V.

Comment: *Any* electromechanical or purely electrical switch will have a rated voltage for the control, and require a good proportion of that to activate the thing.  Welcome to life!

Comment: At that kind of current, you're looking at either a high-power mosfet or igbt module, or a contactor. I'd go with the contactor, personally.

Comment: these ratings are typical step down converter territory. Guess what they use.

Comment: What is the application?

Comment: Some of the comments are wrong. You can get eg 48V switching relays with coils for a wide range of voltages. Typically say 5 12 24 48 V coils. The power needed is the same for a given relay type so current goes up as voltage decreases. If 5V 200 mA is not enough you can use eg a MOSFET to switch the relay at 5V or 12V. The power supply needs to be able to provide the coil current. You can use MOSFETS to swtich voltage but they will be generally more expensive, less robus and trickier to make a true isolated switch with. Solid State relays do the design work for you -  and cost accordingly.

Comment: Knowing the application and all other known details would help us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transistors are good for switching high currents and are used in many high current switching applications.

Mosfets in particular have very low resistance when switched on and can get into the milliohm range which make them suitable for high current.

A n channel mosfet in a "low side configuration" could switch the currents and voltages you want.

---

[image]
Source: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/resistor-configuration-on-mosfet-high-side-low-side-switches/643155

Answer (score 3):

You have not specified the current range, voltage, and switching times.

For fast switching with large V & I you can even use thyristors, although they cannot be turned off at will: in case of an AC waveform they will switch off at the first zero crossing. Thyristors are good to e.g. discharge pulse forming networks and capacitor banks to create large current pulses.

Now available are IGCTs, so thyristors with a high-impedance control gate, that allows turn off and easier driving of the control terminal (the "gate" of "G"). Driving them is a bit more complicated than smaller devices...

Again, large V & I and complete control, you can use IGBTs (handier than older GTOs), possibly need an isolated gate driver for safety and to avoid "backfire" of the steep dV/dt and dI/dt during switching.

At reduced V & I levels, but faster, there are MOSFETs, as mentioned by @VoltageSpike.

You need to clarify a bit your specs, or at least the direction you are looking at.

%added note

Relays give you galvanic isolation, but no more than a few Hz of switching frequency (and they will not last long for large current and voltage values). If you switch DC, then they will die prematurely although you take margins and countermeasures.

With semiconductor devices as above, you are free of going up with the switching frequency, depending on size & technology of course: MOSFETs (or large BJTs) with turn-on/turn-off times of hundreds ns are easily available (BJTs have the problem of turn off and storage time). However, for e.g. >500V and >100A using them becomes impossible (Voltage, hard to put them in series switching at once) or complicated (Current, you can put them in parallel trying to balance the shared current).

IGBTs are good for large inverters e.g. switching 600-1500V, current in excess of 100A. Switching frequency however in the order of 5-20 kHz, not more.